# gradle composite build - modules with same name

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have two library projects with subprojects having same name 'lib', i.e.

```
audio
 \--- lib  

video
 \--- lib
```

And third, main project 'app'.
If in `app/settings.gradle.kt` I try to use composite build with both `audio` and `video`, i.e.

```
includeBuild("../audio")  
includeBuild("../video")
```

error occurs
`Included build "audio" has build path :lib which is the same as included build "video"`

How should I deal with it? Is it possible, when using "includeBuild", specify some prefix or alias to included projects modules, to distinguish it from others?